# The element type 'Iterable<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart

I am making an app using sqlite, and when I try to put the data into widget, I am having an error..
I am following a tutorial and it's giving me this error:
**The element type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.**

```
 FutureBuilder<List<Reminder>>(
          future: _reminders,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              _currentReminders = snapshot.data!;
              return ListView(children: [
                snapshot.data!.map<Widget>((reminder) {
                  return ReminderCard(
                      name: reminder.name, details: reminder.details);
                }).toList(),
```

- new error message:
  **the element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable**
- 

**The element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable
Iterable map(T Function(Reminder) f)
dart:core
Returns a new lazy [Iterable] with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.
This method returns a view of the mapped elements. As long as the returned [Iterable] is not iterated over, the supplied function [f] will not be invoked. The transformed elements will not be cached. Iterating multiple times over the returned [Iterable] will invoke the supplied function [f] multiple times on the same element.
Methods on the returned iterable are allowed to omit calling f on any element where the result isn't needed. For example, [elementAt] may call f only once.**
**Reminder** is the class for DB elements.

```
 Reminder(
      {this.id = 0,
      required this.name,
      required this.details,
      required this.save});

  factory Reminder.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Reminder(
      id: json["id"],
      name: json["name"],
      details: json["details"],
      save: json["false"]);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "details": details,
        "save": save,
      };
}
```

can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `snapshot.data!.map<widget>` - I do not expect that `widget` is a valid type, it should be `Widget`.
2. If you want to use the `.map` function inside ListView children, you should convert map result - iterable - to list and use the spread operator to spread this list inside children:

   ```
   ListView(children: [
     ...snapshot.data!.map<widget>((reminder) {
       return ReminderCard(
         name: reminder.name, details: reminder.details);
     }).toList(),
   ```

Comment: Yes, it's Widget, but I tried to change the type so I forget about the capital letter.

Comment: Could you share the error and the full updated code after the changes?

Comment: well, I updated the code as you told me, but this is the code on github. https://github.com/RarLasebai/reminder3

Comment: I see that you still haven't used the spread operator: `...snapshot.data!.map<Widget>((reminder) {` in line 55, homeScreen.dart.

Comment: Woah, I didn't know that the spread operator is ...

Comment: Thank you, it's true know, but I can't see my floating action button when run the app. Why is that?

Comment: That's a different topic :) Create a new question for this and mark this one as answered.

Comment: Thank you for helping sir. :')

Comment: Hello sir, I need help! could you please check my another question? And sorry for annoying :(