# 'Iterable<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learing flutter and I tried to recreate this from [fireship.io](https://fireship.io/lessons/animated-navigation-flutter-flare/).

I copied the code and I get this Error:

```
The element type 'Iterable<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

Code:

```
    List items = [
        MenuItem(x: -1.0, name: 'house'),
        MenuItem(x: -0.5, name: 'planet'),
        MenuItem(x: 0.0, name: 'camera'),
        MenuItem(x: 0.5, name: 'heart'),
        MenuItem(x: 1.0, name: 'head'),
    ];



Container(
            // <-- 4. Main menu row
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [items.map((item) => _flare(item))],
            ),
          ),
```

Class MenuItem:

```
class MenuItem {
  final String name; // name is the filename of the .flr asset
  final double
      x; // x is the X-axis alignment of the item (-1 is far left, 1 is far right).
  MenuItem({required this.name, required this.x});
```

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962310/the-element-type-iterablewidget-cant-be-assigned-to-the-list-type-widget) with the same error but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: You need to write: `children: items.map((item) => _flare(item)).toList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) returns iterable, so you've to convert that to list. Also you don't need to use [] there.

```
Container(
   child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: items.map((item) => _flare(item)).toList(),
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
  children: [
            ...items.map((item) => _flare(item)).toList(),
          ],
```